# Formflattening and file size reduction / unreferenced objects

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have got a question regarding the behaviour of iText when formflattening and didn't find anything in the web (or just unanswered questions). This is what I do:

```
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

The resulting size is immediately reduced from e.g. 207kb -> 172kb. Directly executing

```
stamper.getReader().removeUnusedObjects();
```

has no effect. If I open the PDF in a text editor i can still find many unreferenced objects in that result file. If I then load the PDF again in a "fresh" stamper and call

```
stamper.getReader().removeUnusedObjects();
```

the Pdf is reduced to 99kb and no unreferenced objects are to be found. 
So here's my question: **Is it possible to immediately (without to re-read the pdf again from file or memory) remove all unreferenced objects from the PDF?** To me its seems that in the first run all direct field related objects are removed but not the indirect referenced dictionaries by those objects.

Comment: Two counter-questions and a remark: (1) why do you use `stamper.getReader().removeUnusedObjects()` instead of `reader.removedUnusedObjects()`? It doesn't make any difference, but I'm curious. (2) Which version of iText are you using? Recent versions trigger `removeUnusedObjects()` automatically (which explains why calling it yourself doesn't have any effect). (3) At the moment the method is called, many objects are still referenced. Only after the flattening process, the references are removed.

Comment: 1) No special reason, you are right I can also use reader.removedUnusedObjects() 2) Ah ok that explains it. I guessed that its implicitly called but wasn't sure thus I'd called it again... 3) But e.g. a signature dictionary solely referenced by a signature field (which itself is correctly removed) is not referenced by any other object but is not removed...

Comment: I know, but keeping an object that isn't needed is safer than throwing away an object that is necessary. If you post-process using `PdfSmartCopy`, you'll discover that you can even pinch away more bytes from the file.

Comment: 1.) But why is it then removed in the 2nd run? This seems to be a bit overcautious... 2) Interesting - so how do I efficently do that on one document? (thougth it is for merging multiple documents?)

Comment: Ah I think I may understand - If you flatten iText is able to remove all form objects. But those objects can reference lots of different indirect objects/dictionaries like fonts, images and other dictionaries like signature dictionaries. One doesn't want to remove a font or an image which is still used thus all indirect objects will be left in the PDF? And this also includes all 'only form field relevant' dictionaries like SignatureDictionaries.

Comment: Yes, `removeUnusedObjects()` loops over the complete xref table and checks if an object is referred to from another object. If not, it's removed. Flattening removes the AcroForm entry, Annots entries, form fields, appearances and widgets, but doesn't go very 'deep' because indeed: a font could be referenced from another object. I should look into the source code to see if there's a way to trigger `removeUnusedObjects` once more in the `close()` method of `PdfStamperImp`. That could solve the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference so that nobody needs to browse through all those comments:

Flattening removes the AcroForm entry, Annots entries, form fields, appearances and widgets, but doesn't go very 'deep' - so e.g. indirect objects referenced by those form fields are not removed. In case those are fonts, images (...) which are still referenced by other objects that is important however if an indirect object is (really) not referenced anymore it will also remain in the pdf. To call the `removeUnusedObjects` on the same instance doesn't help.

The author of iText mentioned he will take a look at the source code to see if there's a way to trigger `removeUnusedObjects` once more in the `close()` method of the `PdfStamperImp`, which could solve that problem.